# Erase a specific marker

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm working on a App in which I have a map with markers that are cabs (like UBER cabs). I'm working with firebase and the thing is I need to erase just the marker (the child on firebase) which has changed its location, if the others haven't change yet I need to keep them in the map... I have already worked on a function but it erases every single marker from the map, not just the one(the cab) that has "moved"...

```
 private void loadLocationsFromCloud() {

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    String company= extras.getString("cabs-company").toString();
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("company");
    Query groupQuery = myRef.child(company);

    groupQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
          //nothing to do here.
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange");
            eraseMarkers();
            LastLocation item = dataSnapshot.getValue(LastLocation.class);
            LatLng newLatLng = new LatLng(item.getmLatitud(), 
            item.getmLongitud());
            Integer cabId = new Integer(item.getcabId());
            drawMarker(newLatLng, cabId);

            
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange");

       
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
           
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

//the method to draw the marker

```
  private void drawMarker(LatLng pos, final Integer cabId) {
    final String id = cabId.toString();
    final String cabId = "u" + id;
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String company = bundle.getString("company");
    final MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(pos);
    markerOptions.position(pos);
    
 markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.rutixxx));
    markerOptions.snippet("Cab #: " + num);
    markerOptions.title(company);


    if (mMap != null) {
        marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
        markersToClear.add(marker);
    }

}
```

//the method to erase markers.

```
 private void eraseMarkers() {

    for (Marker marker : markersToClear) {
        marker.remove();
    }
    markersToClear.clear();
}
```

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

In the method `drawMarker`, you **add all the markers** into `markersToClear`, ofcourse all will the markers will be errased when you call the function `eraseMarkers`.

I think you should just add the markers into markersToClear **when the marker is changed**. Maybe there is a `change event listener` in android, try to use it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, i've been searching for a change event listener but cant resolve the issue... the thing is that theese "variables" (latitude, longitude of the cab that has change its position) come from a firebase database and that's why i dont know how to make conditions with them...

Comment: i've been thinking about a hashmap, but not quite sure how to introduce the markers on it.}